# Why we need to remove payment observer when app will terminated?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

Why we need to remove payment observer when app will terminated?

[image: Example image]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it's possible that you don't "need" to remove the payment observer on app termination.  If iOS does something on the OS side of things, it *might* be necessary, but I would think that would be a bug in iOS... it should clean up all resources used by an app on app termination.  There's also the possibility that there is some AppStore protocol that it uses where it's good practice to tell the server you're not interested in observing payments anymore.   It's generally a good idea to clean up resources, but often it's not strictly necessary (like closing files).

Comment: This is a recommendation from the Apple documentation, but I did not find an explanation for this, here is the link - app_purchase/setting_up_the_transaction_observer_for_the_payment_queue.

Comment: Since the reasoning for recommendation isn't explained, I think it would be better to assume that removing the payment observer is somehow needed by the OS for its clean-up.   Even if that's not the case, and it's simply Apple conveying a specific instance of the general "clean up before you quit" advise, it's still a good idea, because some future OS version might change the way it does things so that is is necessary.